# How many people can connect to one port?

Tags: sockets, ftp, port

Hi this will be an easy question.

Ftp, as an example, works on ports 20, 21. How many different people can connect to the same ftp server on the same port (21) at the same time?

Comment: It depends, can be from 1-8 as far as i know.

Comment: This depends on if you are using IIS FTP or 3rd party FTP software's ;ike FileZilla

Comment: Then what happens when more people (over the limit) want to connect?

Comment: You need to read up on the FTP Site Default settings. This should answer your question

Answer (score 1):

As many as the server and the server OS can handle. There is no specific limit.

All the comments citing specific clients are incorrect, as is the one stating '1-8 as far as I know.' The comment about 'FTP Site Default settings' only applies to Microsoft IIS.

Comment: I agree that there is no limit but since this was an open question, if you install FTP on Windows XP, the limitation will be restricted to 10 except you hack the registry

Comment: @Chelseawillrecover Please be clear and please be specific. You are describing the *Microsoft* FTP server built into IIS. One piece of software. That certainly is not a general rule applying to all FTP servers, let alone all ports.

Answer (score 0):

Port is the virtual interfacing used to differentiate services. In your case FTP server listen on particular port 21 which differentiate all other services/servers running on the same system listening to the same IP address (eg: DHCP server on 67 etc.,).

So the port are used only at Transport and Application layer (to bind to the particular port). The number of connections is limited with the help of "listen" system call (in case of linux), which will used in server binding.

Note: Observe any PCAP traces and socket programming to understand the usage of port.

Comment: The number of connections is not limited either by or 'with the help of' the `listen()` system call. That only limits the backlog. As that's the only part of your post that answers the question, -1.